# How to reduce CPU consumption by using avconv and pipe it to avplay?

Tags: performance, capture, avconv, screencast

**See FINAL EDIT.**

I need to capture the second monitor and show in main display in a small window. I don't need quality, but performance.

So, the (working) command to capture second monitor of 1280x1024 and show it in a 640x480 window  at 15fps and horizonatally flipped, would be (from [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667240/how-do-i-play-a-video-with-audio-from-a-separate-file-mux-during-playback)):

```
avconv -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1280x1024 -i :0.1 -c:v mpeg4 \
  -b:v 1000k -s 640x480 -vf "hflip" -f avi - | avplay -i -
```

- How to scale with "None" interpolation?
- I used "-c:v mpeg4" and "-b:v 1000k" to have a good image quality, but... is there any other format/bitrate to reduce at minimum the CPU consumption?
- I know that horizontal flipping is a basic effect, but is there any way to tell avconv to reduce CPU by using -vf option?
- When the playing window stars showing, its 15fps is respected. But then, it gets lower and lower progresively to gets freezed... until I click the window. Then, it is rises to 15fps and gets lower again. Why it is like this and how to avoid it? I tried to use "nice -n-20" with both avconv and avplay, but it makes no difference.

When I say that I need performance, not quality, I say that it's more important to save CPU... but **I don't want to see a full-of-low-compression-artifacts video**.

I'm on Ubuntu-Mate 14.04.

Thanks!

**FINAL EDIT**: the command would be:

```
avconv -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1280x1024 -i :0.0+1920 -c:v mpeg4 \
-b:v 1000k -vf "hflip" -vf "scale=640:480" -sws_flags "neighbor" \
-f avi - | avplay -i -
```

But the framerate issue is not solved and it consumes 16-18% CPU. In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747500/using-gstreamer-to-capture-screen-and-show-it-in-a-window), there is the Gstreamer option, with gst-launch: it consumes 2-4% CPU. So, the avconvert/avplay option is not usefull for me.

Comment: From #libav, user JEEB helped me. The first question is resolved (using -vf "scale=640:480" -sws_flags "neighbor"), the second is a matter of tests, the third has no much sense... but there's a big problem with the FPS (edited to clarify it). When I resolve this last issue, I'll post a complete answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try with using the `framerate` option for x11grab.

Comment: I didn't find the difference with "-r", but "-framerate" does not solve the problem.