# transmit screen buffer of a specific application to a remote system and reproduce image from that (in windows)

Tags: windows, networking, buffer, screen, video-capture

I know, there are apps out there like steam, Xbox that streams the game video onto  network. What I want is the same thing but i need to make my own code for the purpose (open source), so that I may amend it for different applications without any copyright issues. I know Winsock programming and can transmit sample videos (mp4 files) but this thing of capturing the display on one system and producing it on some remote system is different and much complicated (i suppose). Plus, the streaming needs to be live with minimum delays. I have access to gigabit ethernet to address slow fps issues but first i need to transmit recieve a sample buffer
If someone please guide me on how to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org) is the closest thing to what you want.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747500/using-gstreamer-to-capture-screen-and-show-it-in-a-window) and [here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/gstreamer-windows-d9xscreencapture-and-tcpclientsink-td4661281.html) for more info.

Also, look at [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop).

Comment: regarding ffmpeg, it only captures the whole screen but what i want is to capture the screen buffer of only a certain application display... but that gstreamer thing, i think it will do for me. I have installed gstreamer but since I am new to this world, I don't know where to start. I have MS Visual studio 2015. If you can hint on someone who knows these things and help me to get started

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is OBS studio. It is open source which allows me to edit the source code as to fulfill my needs. However, I had to implement a nginx-rtmp server on the client end to receive the video. I then used vlc media player to stream the video received by the rtmp server. I have Gtx 960m installed so I implemented harware encoding which allowed me to stream 720p @60 fps over 100 Mbps ethernet cable. The results were drastic when I used software encoder (instead of hardware) before streaming.